# Regex not matching in Fastify route

Tags: javascript, regex, fastify

I decided to port my code from Express to Fastify. So this is a big headache when we haven't set proper testing.

Anyway, the route is declared as:

`fastify.get(/^\/(donations|skills|blogs)/, async function (req, reply) {`

It was working in Express but in Fastify it is returning 404. I'm sure it has to do with regex itself as other routes inside the same plugin/file/ are working properly.

It is supposed to match `/listings/donations` or `listings/skills`... knowing that `/listings` is the prefix when attaching the whole routing plugin to the app.

[Regex working](https://regex101.com/r/Uxlqr3/1)

Comment: If there is a prefix, why not add it to the pattern? Like `/^\/listings\/(donations|skills|blogs)/`

Comment: It is better to keep it in the place where this router is mounted. In  app.js for instance, I'm mounting *listings" route with their prefix. Also mounting "messages" route with their prefix and so on... A way of organisation basically. For sake of testing it doesn't work similarly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reply to your answer, you can't provide a RegExp object to Fastify. You need to set a path-parameter within a RegExp:

```
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true })

const handler = async (request, reply) => {
  return { hello: request.params.foo }
}

fastify.get('/listings/:foo(^(donations|skills|blogs)$)', handler)
fastify.listen(8080)
```

*(I think you should get an error for your setup so I opened [an issue](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/issues/3648))*

As a suggestion you should not do it: you will hit a performance drop cause of this regexp.
I would suggest you write it like so:

```
fastify.get('/listings/donations)', handler)
fastify.get('/listings/skills)', handler)
fastify.get('/listings/blogs', handler)
```

Let the router does its job.

Here is the performance comparison:

#### With RegExp

```
┌───────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ Stat      │ 1%      │ 2.5%    │ 50%     │ 97.5%   │ Avg      │ Stdev   │ Min     │
├───────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ Req/Sec   │ 68863   │ 68863   │ 75327   │ 75839   │ 73678.55 │ 2791.45 │ 68860   │
├───────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ Bytes/Sec │ 12.5 MB │ 12.5 MB │ 13.7 MB │ 13.8 MB │ 13.4 MB  │ 507 kB  │ 12.5 MB │
└───────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

#### Without RegExp

```
┌───────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ Stat      │ 1%      │ 2.5%    │ 50%     │ 97.5%   │ Avg      │ Stdev   │ Min     │
├───────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ Req/Sec   │ 86015   │ 86015   │ 95423   │ 95551   │ 94350.55 │ 2681.36 │ 85954   │
├───────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ Bytes/Sec │ 15.6 MB │ 15.6 MB │ 17.4 MB │ 17.4 MB │ 17.2 MB  │ 491 kB  │ 15.6 MB │
└───────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: Indeed. This is the solution for now. As Fastify is performance in mind, I understand that Regex can be avoided in the implementation. Otherwise, this is not intended as an API and I believe it might not affect performance that much. Anyway, I'm opting for the second solution.